# How to override a method in a subclass and call the parent class method without losing data

Tags: java, methods, overriding, super

> *This is only the second time I use this, and the first time I got really good help so I am hoping I could get some more help!*

**Background:**

My program tests my `Account` class by creating an object that holds a balance and other things. The instructions say I need to override the subclasse's **"Withdraw"** and **"Deposit"** methods in order to keep track of a transaction.

I did this, but it doesn't use the current balance and instead just sends in a 0. I want to be able to keep the new balance so it actually withdraws or deposits from the current balance.

*Sorry if this makes no sense, if any clarification is needed I will try to explain in a different way.*

**Below is my code snippet:**

> **Note:** I kept out the stuff that already works *(constructors and other methods)* that has nothing to do with this:

**Account.java**

```
public class Account
{    
    private static double balance;

    public void Withdraw(double withdrawAmount)
    {
        this.balance -= withdrawAmount;
    }
    public void Deposit(double depositAmount)
    {
        this.balance += depositAmount;
    }
}
```

**UserAccount.java**

```
public class UserAccount extends Account
{
    private ArrayList<Transactions> transactions = new ArrayList();
    @Override
    public void Withdraw(double withdrawAmount)
    {
        super.Withdraw(withdrawAmount);
        Transactions thisTransaction = new Transactions('W', 
        withdrawAmount, this.AccBalance(), "Withdraw");
        this.transactions.add(thisTransaction);
    }
    @Override
    public void Deposit(double depositAmount)
    {
        super.Deposit(depositAmount);
        Transactions thisTransaction = new Transactions('D', 
        depositAmount, this.AccBalance(), "Deposit");
        this.transactions.add(thisTransaction);
    }
    public void fillTransactions(char type, double amount, double balance)
    {
        switch (type) {
            case 'D':
                this.Deposit(amount);
                break;
            case 'W':
                this.Withdraw(amount);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("ERROR fillTransactions");
                break;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Transactions> copyTransactions;
        UserAccount thisAccount = new UserAccount("George", 1122, 1000);
        thisAccount.MutAIR(.015);

        thisAccount.fillTransactions('D', 30, thisAccount.AccBalance());
        thisAccount.fillTransactions('D', 40, thisAccount.AccBalance());
        thisAccount.fillTransactions('D', 50, thisAccount.AccBalance());
        thisAccount.fillTransactions('W', 5, thisAccount.AccBalance());
        thisAccount.fillTransactions('W', 4, thisAccount.AccBalance());
        thisAccount.fillTransactions('W', 2, thisAccount.AccBalance());
}
```

The `Transactions` class that I have holds the type *(withdraw or deposit)*, the amount getting withdrawn or deposited, and the balance. What happening is when I call the super class from the overridden deposit or withdraw methods, it sets balance to 0 so it says that the balance is 50, or 40, or -5 when I want the original balance with the deposited or withdrawn currency.

If anyone could help, that would be amazing! I can clarify if anything is confusing! Thank you!

Comment: a couple of things 1. `balance` param in `fillTransactions` is not used. Are you sure you want to use this param.   2. How does your `UserAccount.AccBalance()` function look like.  3. `balance` in `Account` should NOT be static as you probably want it to be different for each instance of `Account`

Comment: The instructions stated that it wanted my getters and setters to be static, so in order for the compiler to not scream at me I set it to static. My code looks like this for access balance. It is basically a getter, just abbreviated public static double AccBalance()
    {
        return balance;
    }

Comment: the function `AccBalance` and `balance` should not be static IMHO. I hope you know difference between static and non-static variables in Java

Comment: Just curious, is this a homework problem ?

Comment: I do know the difference, thats why I am confused as to why my professor wants it all static. It has made this so confusing and I don't know how to work around static. Any ideas on how I can work around it. make a copy of it?

Comment: yes, this is a homework problem. He just changed it by "adding" a few additions to the assignment. One was making everything static in the parent class

Comment: everythnig refers to just variables or methods too?

Comment: It says to make accessors and mutators static

Comment: since Deposit and Withdraw are mutators here, i guess he means that too. But when u do make them static, I wonder how would you override them in subclass.

Comment: It works perfectly fine if balance isn't static, so I think I may just keep it at that. otherwise, I don't know what to do with it..

Comment: I think the answer posted here should fix it. As an aside, would suggest you to refer `balance` by Account.GetBalance() and Account.setBalance()` static methods instead of `this.balance`

Comment: If if works fine without static, i guess you are autogenerating constructor using lombok plugin?

Comment: I have a constructor, all I am doing is just calling the parent class and changing it using the method from their. Not sure what lombok plugin is?

Comment: I also have one more question. I am going to try to keep a variable called annual interest rate as static, and I am trying to call it just for output using my getter method. Both the getter method and variable are static, but it is outputting 0. Do you know how I can fix this? I can send u my code for that if needed

Comment: Are you initializing Account.balance from UserAccount constructor?

Comment: Yes, I am. That as well as the annual interest rate

Comment: I am out of idea then, the code looks fine to me. Try referencing all static variables by class names instead of `this` everywhere and check. As static variables are initialized only once, what you are describing should not happen. Will try out your example when i get some free time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I think you are not setting the balance in the constructor of UserAccount. 
Here's an example of setting variable
Assume class A as Account and class B as UserAccount

```
class A {
  private double balance;// Don't use static
  public A(double balance) {// You will need this
      this.balance = balance;
  }
  public double getBalance() { return balance; }
}
class B extends A {
  public B(double balance) { 
      super(balance);//Important
  }
  public void d() { System.out.println(getBalance()); }
}
public class Main {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    B b = new B(100.0);
    b.d();
  }
}
```

If you use static balance in the super class, then only one instance of it will be used for all the objects, since you want individual balance for each UserAccount I guess.

Comment: I would prefer if instead of `this.balance` you use `A.balance` just to make explicit that `balance` is static

Comment: I changed balance to be non-static. This makes sense, thank you!